# What triggers healers in Clan Castle?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When defending only troops in the Clan Castle that can attack air targets will come out when only air units enter the range of the Clan Castle. Will the healer come out as well or will she stay in the Clan Castle even if heroes and other Clan Castles are taking damage but no ground troops are deployed by the attacker?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the healer will come out as well as she will heal your King, Queen, and other ground troops from your cc.

Comment: Not buildings, that feature was removed

Comment: @ModDL Wow really?? I had no idea! Do you have any more info on when and why they removed it?

Comment: @Alex This was removed in the September 2014 update, no idea why though.

Comment: I just got attacked with all dragons. my healers did not deploy, hope you are hit with other troops!

Answer (score 0):

In War, the CC healer will not deploy on dragons. CC Air & ground Wizards will deploy on dragons, but the healer will not deploy to heal them. The CC healer will only deploy when an attacking ground troop comes into CC range. (Seems backwards to me)

Comment: Do you have any sources or proofs?

Comment: Probably a rule technical reason, as the "target" for healers are ground troops, even if this is a special case since the "target" is your own troops. So since the target is ground only, it will not trigger when attacked by air units. Reason is probably complexity in the AI.